# Use Python to arrange data in excel or import data to python and then arrange?

Tags: python, excel

I am new to Python and want to use it to arrange, analyse and plot some data (several thousand). So normally what process do you use?

1. import all data in python and do all the arrangement, analyses and plotting in python
2. use python to control excel and do all the arrangement, analyses and plotting in excel
3. do some parts in excel, do some parts in python

Currently, I choose 2, but I am not sure if it is a standard process. I also found that if importing all data in python, it's not even able to view all the data in a very convenient way, then how to arrange those data or do other tricks?

Answer (score 1):

The best & easy way would be the first point i,e. **import all data in python and do all the arrangement, analyses and plotting in python**

Read Excel file using pandas

```
import pandas as pf
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

**Then use matplotlib, for plotting as you require**

Comment: but my concern is that it is really difficult to check if I made the correct change in python as it uses ellipsis(...) to represent data just to fit in the width of the console, which is not like excel that you can see all your data at the same time.

Comment: @Elizabeth, as you get more comfortable with Python and slicing parts of the data, you will know how to view the relevant bits of your data to see if the changes you made are the ones you wanted. Also, you can write a script that verifies things for you. In any case, it is usually better to work only in one environment. I personally don't like `pandas`, but I am very comfortable with `numpy` and saving data in `mongo`. You are just going to have to try things and see what suits you best. Perhaps the answer will be to just keep working in `excel`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'pandas' library to import data, just rename your .excel file to .csv:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

For Plotting and analysis you can use 'matplotlib' library, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
time = [0, 1, 2, 3]
position = [0, 100, 200, 300]
plt.plot(time, position)
plt.xlabel('Time (hr)')
plt.ylabel('Position (km)')
```

Comment: simply renaming a `xls` file to `csv` doesn't work, as `xls` files are binary files and `csv` is plain text. Also, you are not really addressing the question.

Comment: yes, you are right. Thank you for correcting me and share your useful knowledge.